# Arreglo dinámico en c

Tags: c, array

Estaba haciendo un arreglo dinámico, pero tengo un pequeño problema, seguro que sencillo pero no soy capaz de verlo.. Introduzco la dimensión de elementos que quiero y meto la cantidad de elementos según esa dimensión, pero a la hora de visualizar no lo hace

Codigo:

```
//Prototipos de funciones
void introducirDatos(int cantidad,int *x);
void visualizarDatos(int cantidad,int *x);

int main()
{
    int cantidad,*x;

    introducirDatos(cantidad,x);
    visualizarDatos(cantidad,x);

    return 0;
}

void introducirDatos(int cantidad,int *x)
{

    printf("Introduce la cantidad de elementos del arreglo: ");
    scanf("%d",&cantidad);

    x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    if(x==NULL)
    {
        printf("No se a podido reservar memoria");
    }   
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
        {
            printf("Dato: ");
            scanf("%d",&x[i]);
        }
    }
}

void visualizarDatos(int cantidad,int *x)
{
    for(int i=0;i<cantidad;i++)
    {
        printf("%d ",x[i]);
    }
    free(x);
}
```

Comment: Cuando las llamas en el main no le estas asignando valores, 
    **introducirDatos(cantidad,x);
    visualizarDatos(cantidad,x);** Prueba asi, introducirDatos(5, 2);

Comment: ¿`x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));` no debería ser `x = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * cantidad);`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para esta función:

```
void introducirDatos(int cantidad,int *x)
```

`x` es un puntero simple, es decir, lo apuntado por `x` podrá ser visible fuera de la función... pero los cambios en `x` son cambios locales. Un ejemplo más sencillo de ver:

```
void func(int var)
{ var = 10; }

int main()
{
  int a = 0;
  func(a);
  printf("%d",a);
}
```

¿Qué valor imprime el programa?

La respuesta es sencilla, 0, porque `func` hace cambios locales. Pues a un puntero le pasa lo mismo:

```
void func(int* var)
{ var = 10; }

int main()
{
  int* a = 0;
  func(a);

  // ¿A donde apunta el puntero?
}
```

El ejemplo es exactamente el mismo... el puntero `a` no ha visto modificada su dirección de memoria. Los cambios en `func` son locales.

¿Cómo solucionar este problema? Aumentando el nivel de indirección. Si para modificar una variable dentro de una función necesitamos pasar un puntero en vez de la variable por valor...

```
void func(int* a)
{ *a = 10; }
```

... para reasignar un puntero simple necesitamos que la función reciba un puntero doble:

```
void func(int** a)
{ *a = malloc(100); }
```

¿Y para reasignar un puntero doble? Entonces necesitaremos un puntero triple y así hasta el infinito.